# hibernate query list method is returning list size 3 while table rows is 4

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

**hibernate query list method is returning list size 3 while table rows is 4 and when i fire query  on this table by use of returned primary key then show null pointer exception**

> //status is table_field which is zero for all row

```
session.register(bean);
session.getTransaction.commit();
```

> //after this transaction, table abc have 4 rows
>
> //after this line we access data

```
select from abc where status=0;
```

> //i got list size 3 //last row not have in list
>
> this method return hibernate session

```
public static Session getHiber(){

        AnnotationConfiguration anob = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        anob.configure("hiber.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =  anob.buildSessionFactory();
         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        return session;
}
```

> this method save bean

```
public Integer register(Object u){
    Session session =HiberSession.getHiber();
    Integer x =(Integer)session.save(u);        
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Have you fired the query and see in database ?

Comment: Are you sure the `bean` you save has `status==0`? Post more code. At this point trying to answer this question is just guessing.

Comment: Hibernate won't behave like that, can you directly hit the same query on DB and compare the results

Comment: yes i  fired the query and see in database .

Comment: on command prompt i seen status and new row,i mean 4th row.

Comment: somehow current transaction is not able to see the data that has been commited.

Comment: Post more code, it is not possible to analyze the issue with the information that you have given

Comment: i post more code....

Comment: What is your flush mode?

Comment: commit flush mode is used by me..